# Left aligning text at center along with multiple equations

Tags: vertical-alignment, text

[What is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EoUZ.jpg)
[image: What I want]
I am writing a few equations with gathered and aligned. The problem is that A and B are left aligned with the first equation, and I want them at the center of all equations, whether 2 or more. Here is my MWE.

```
\begin{flalign*}
      \begin{gathered}
        A \quad \vphantom{a = b} \\
                \vphantom{=c} \\
        B \quad \vphantom{e = f} \\
                \vphantom{=g}
      \end{gathered}
      &&
      \begin{aligned}
        a &= b \\
          &= c \\
        e &= f \\
          &= g
      \end{aligned}
      &&
    \end{flalign*}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Try to insert an image, please.

Comment: Thanks. Is it clear now? The top figure is what I want. The link shows what is there. I don't know why these are displayed like that, because I added both in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wish?

```
\begin{flalign*}A && \begin{aligned} a &= b \\ &= c \end{aligned} && \end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}B && \begin{aligned} e &= f \\ &= g \end{aligned} && \end{flalign*}

\[
\begin{gathered}
A \quad \begin{aligned} a&=b\\  &=c \end{aligned} \\ 
B \quad \begin{aligned} d&=e\\  &=f \end{aligned} \\ 
\end{gathered}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly right. However, in case equations have different heights (like summations or integrals), \vphantom was adjusting it. Can it be done in your code?

Comment: Do you mean in second example? There `A` is vertical centred.

Comment: Your first code is what I wanted, and I just confirmed that it is aligning for heights. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: @QasimChaudhari, you are welcomed.

Comment: As a general question, should I abandon using my MWE code all together and start using this one for all siutations, or there are some advantages in using \gathered and \vphantom?

Comment: @QasimChaudhari, I would use my command, not yours. I recommend you to change.